# Android TV emulator input not forwarding from host machine keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]

I'd like to control an Android TV emulator with the host computer keyboard but I'm running into an issue where the keyboard input is not forwarding onto the emulator. The left, right, down, up arrow keys, enter, and esc don't move the leanback UI selection (left, right, up, down, select, and back). It doesn't work when the emulator is launched in Android Studio or when launched from the command line. For example in the above screenshot pressing the up arrow does not move the selection up to "Reality" section. I'm using Android Studio Jellyfish Canary 4 on macOS Monterey. Is there a setting or something I'm missing?

Also enabling "hardware input" doesn't have any effect.

[image]

dPad and keyboard are enabled:

```
hw.dPad = yes
hw.keyboard = yes
```

This what `config.ini` looks like:

```
AvdId = Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2
PlayStore.enabled = false
abi.type = x86
avd.ini.displayname = Android TV (1080p) API 30 2
avd.ini.encoding = UTF-8
disk.dataPartition.size = 6442450944
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile =
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot = no
fastboot.forceColdBoot = no
fastboot.forceFastBoot = yes
hw.accelerometer = no
hw.arc = false
hw.audioInput = yes
hw.battery = no
hw.camera.back = None
hw.camera.front = None
hw.cpu.arch = x86
hw.cpu.ncore = 4
hw.dPad = yes
hw.device.hash2 = MD5:41e6ce015774b2a310e5fdbbd3964241
hw.device.manufacturer = Google
hw.device.name = tv_1080p
hw.gps = yes
hw.gpu.enabled = yes
hw.gpu.mode = auto
hw.initialOrientation = landscape
hw.keyboard = yes
hw.keyboard.lid = yes
hw.lcd.density = 320
hw.lcd.height = 1080
hw.lcd.width = 1920
hw.mainKeys = yes
hw.ramSize = 1536
hw.sdCard = yes
hw.sensors.orientation = no
hw.sensors.proximity = no
hw.trackBall = no
image.sysdir.1 = system-images/android-30/google-tv/x86/
runtime.network.latency = none
runtime.network.speed = full
sdcard.path = /Users/180238/.android/avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd/sdcard.img
sdcard.size = 512 MB
showDeviceFrame = no
skin.dynamic = yes
skin.name = 1920x1080
skin.path = _no_skin
skin.path.backup = _no_skin
tag.display = Google TV
tag.id = google-tv
vm.heapSize = 48
```

And here's `hardware-qemu.ini` (both in `~/.android/avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd`):

```
hw.cpu.arch = x86
hw.cpu.model = qemu32
hw.cpu.ncore = 4
hw.ramSize = 2048
hw.screen = multi-touch
hw.mainKeys = true
hw.trackBall = false
hw.keyboard = true
hw.keyboard.lid = true
hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
hw.dPad = true
hw.rotaryInput = false
hw.gsmModem = true
hw.gps = true
hw.battery = false
hw.accelerometer = false
hw.accelerometer_uncalibrated = true
hw.gyroscope = true
hw.audioInput = true
hw.audioOutput = true
hw.sdCard = true
hw.sdCard.path = /Users/180238/.android/avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd/sdcard.img
disk.cachePartition = true
disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/180238/.android/avd/../avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd/cache.img
disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
test.monitorAdb = 0
hw.lcd.width = 1920
hw.lcd.height = 1080
hw.lcd.depth = 16
hw.lcd.circular = false
hw.lcd.density = 320
hw.lcd.backlight = true
hw.lcd.vsync = 60
hw.gltransport = pipe
hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800
hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
hw.displayRegion.0.2.xOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.2.yOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.2.width = 0
hw.displayRegion.0.2.height = 0
hw.displayRegion.0.3.xOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.3.yOffset = -1
hw.displayRegion.0.3.width = 0
hw.displayRegion.0.3.height = 0
hw.display1.width = 0
hw.display1.height = 0
hw.display1.density = 0
hw.display1.xOffset = -1
hw.display1.yOffset = -1
hw.display1.flag = 0
hw.display2.width = 0
hw.display2.height = 0
hw.display2.density = 0
hw.display2.xOffset = -1
hw.display2.yOffset = -1
hw.display2.flag = 0
hw.display3.width = 0
hw.display3.height = 0
hw.display3.density = 0
hw.display3.xOffset = -1
hw.display3.yOffset = -1
hw.display3.flag = 0
hw.multi_display_window = false
hw.hotplug_multi_display = false
hw.gpu.enabled = true
hw.gpu.mode = host
hw.initialOrientation = landscape
hw.camera.back = None
hw.camera.front = None
vm.heapSize = 512
hw.sensors.light = true
hw.sensors.pressure = true
hw.sensors.humidity = true
hw.sensors.proximity = false
hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
hw.sensors.orientation = false
hw.sensors.temperature = true
hw.sensors.rgbclight = false
hw.sensor.hinge = false
hw.sensor.hinge.count = 0
hw.sensor.hinge.type = 0
hw.sensor.hinge.sub_type = 0
hw.sensor.hinge.fold_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 1
hw.sensor.roll = false
hw.sensor.roll.count = 0
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 6
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.2_at_posture = 6
hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.3_at_posture = 6
hw.sensors.heart_rate = false
hw.sensors.wrist_tilt = false
hw.useext4 = true
hw.arc = false
hw.arc.autologin = false
hw.device.name = tv_1080p
kernel.path = /Users/180238/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google-tv/x86//kernel-ranchu-64
kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
disk.ramdisk.path = /Users/180238/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google-tv/x86//ramdisk.img
disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/180238/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google-tv/x86//system.img
disk.systemPartition.size = 3083m
disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /Users/180238/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google-tv/x86//vendor.img
disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/180238/.android/avd/../avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd/userdata-qemu.img
disk.dataPartition.size = 6g
disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /Users/180238/.android/avd/../avd/Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2.avd/encryptionkey.img
PlayStore.enabled = false
avd.name = Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2
avd.id = Android_TV_1080p_API_30_2
fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
userdata.useQcow2 = false
firstboot.bootFromDownloadableSnapshot = true
firstboot.bootFromLocalSnapshot = true
firstboot.saveToLocalSnapshot = true
android.sdk.root = /Users/180238/Library/Android/sdk
android.avd.home = /Users/180238/.android/avd
```